# Inheriting a template with constraints (not in a C+20 sense)

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, wrapper

Coming from JavaScript I've always pondered on their events and handlers. Therefore I wanted to make some C++ counterpart to it. I'm expecting from the final product this kind of behavior

```cpp
// Button.cpp
void press(const Vector2f& pos){ //Vector2f - vector of 2 floats in math sense
   if(this->check_if_inside(pos))
      this->evoke(Button::Event::ButtonPressed{});
}

// Controller.cpp
void init() {
   Button button{/*some params*/};
   button.addEventListener(Button::Event::ButtonPressed, []{
      std::cout << "I'm pressed!";
   });

   this->buttons[0] = button;
}

void loop() {
   while(auto e = window_events.poll()){
      if(e.type == eType::MouseClick){
         for(auto& button : this->buttons)
            button.press(e.pos);
      }
   }
}
```

I've tried implementing it generically via this "Eventable" class-wrapper

```cpp
template <class C>
class Eventable {
    // We expect that class C being Eventable has some Event struct inside of it;
    typedef typename C::Event CEvent;
    // And a corresponding enum of possible types
    typedef typename CEvent::EventType CEventType;

    std::list<std::function<void(const CEvent&)>> event_listeners{};
public:
// other stuff like .addEventHandler and so on
};
```

But then when I try to use it

```cpp
class Button: public Eventable<Button> {
    struct Event {
        enum struct EventType {ButtonPressed}
        EventType type;
    
        struct ButtonPressed {};
    };
}
```

I get error of compiler not knowing what "Event" of "Button" is (it says "incorrect use of incomplete type "class Button"). And there is no way of forward declaring Button::Event whatsoever. So the question is - is there a way to make it work? How to say to the template "hey, you want from me a event subclass, here, there you have it"?

Comment: What's `CEvent`, and how, if at all, is it related to `Event`? Anyway, the problem is that `Eventable<Button>` is instantiated while `Button` is still an incomplete type, and none of its members have been seen. One workaround would be to move `Event` definition outside of `Button` class; name it something like `ButtonEvent`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik CEvent is an alias for C::Event, as written. There in Eventable I expect the class C to have internal subclass Event that has an internal enum EventType. Is there a way to do that? I know about abstract classes and virtual methods, but I haven't seen interfaces for subclasses

Comment: You can refer to members of `C` inside member functions of `Eventable<C>`, but not in any declarations in the definition of `Eventable`. Again, because at the time `Eventable<Button>` is instantiated, no part of `Button` has yet been seen beyond its name. The search term for further research is "CRTP", short for "Curiously recurring template pattern".

Comment: Again, a possible workaround might go like this: `struct ButtonEvent {...}; class Button: public Eventable<Button, ButtonEvent> {...};` In fact, it doesn't look like `Eventable` even needs `Button` - it just needs to take `ButtonEvent` as a parameter. Then it won't be CRTP.

Comment: Actually getting rid of `Button` as a template parameter worked! A desirable addition would be a pointer to `Button` in `ButtonEvent`, but forward declaration would be the way to do it.
So as I understood, you will definitely need to bring `Event` outside of `Button` and rename it to `ButtonEvent` and there is no way that `ButtonEvent` could be inside `Button`? Now it's just a matter of where I want to put my code :D And the whole point of putting events inside button is to get rid of 'button' in the name of event

Comment: You could do `class Button ... { using Event = ButtonEvent; }` and then use `Button::Event` most places, and `ButtonEvent` where you can't.